# How to build a slider in react js or javascript without using material ui slider

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a slider in react js but don't know how to implement this without using any third-party plugins.

Something similar to this https://mui.com/components/slider/

Answer (score 1):

You can try Something like this:

```js
class Slider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { value: 0 };
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
  }

  changeValue() {
    this.setState({ value: this.refs.input.value * this.props.max });
  }

  render() {
    const sliderStyle = {
      position: "relative",
      width: "284px",
      height: "28px"
    };

    const rangeStyle = {
      webkitAppearance: "none",
      appearance: "none",
      touchAction: "pan-y",
      position: "absolute",
      margin: "0",
      padding: "0",
      width: "284px",
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    };

    const progressBarStyle = {
      webkitAppearance: "none",
      appearance: "none",
      position: "absolute",
      display: "block",
      margin: "0",
      top: "13px",
      left: "13px",
      width: "256px",
      height: "3px",
      zIndex: "-1",
      backgroundColor: "#D7D7D7"
    };

    return (
      <div
        style={sliderStyle}
        aria-valuemin={this.props.min}
        aria-valuemax={this.props.max}
        aria-valuenow={this.state.value}
        aria-valuetext={this.state.value}
      >
        <input
          ref="input"
          type="range"
          onChange={this.changeValue}
          defaultValue={this.props.min}
          min={this.props.min}
          max={this.props.max}
          step={this.props.max / 100}
          style={rangeStyle}
        />
        <progress
          value={this.state.value}
          min={this.props.min}
          max={this.props.max}
          style={progressBarStyle}
        ></progress>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Slider min={0} max={1} />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
:root {
  --thumb-shadow:
      0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15),
      0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16),
      0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .10)
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display:  -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #EFEFF4
}

* { outline: none }

progress::-webkit-progress-value { background-color: #007AFF }

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  overflow: hidden
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: var(--thumb-shadow)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=root>
</div>
```